# Present view controller asynchronously in background

Tags: ios, swift, background, presentviewcontroller

I send an async request and I present a view controller when I receive success. It works.

But I'm getting an issue when my app is in background when I receive success and that I pass it in foreground. The view controller is not always displayed.

I think it's about the main thread but I'm not sure.

How can I fix it ?

EDIT:

Here is the function that I call after the success:

```
func showPopup(on viewController: UIViewController) {
    let viewControllerToPresent = MyPopupViewController(nibName: "Popup", bundle: nil)

    let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: viewControllerToPresent, buttonAlignment: .horizontal, transitionStyle: .zoomIn, gestureDismissal: false)

    let button = DefaultButton(title: "Ok") {
        popup.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    popup.addButtons([button])
    viewController.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Where is the code? What you've tried?

Comment: The code above doesn't show anything being called in the background. Please show all _relevant_ code. Thanks

Comment: There is no other relevant code.

Comment: The code that calls `showPopup` is relevant.

Comment: `showPopup` is called in the success of my async request

Comment: Please show the code that calls `showPopup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your application is in the background, i.e. suspended, Apple doesn't allow you to make any changes substantive changes to the user interface.  In this case your best approach is probably to save that you want to do something on return and check in your App Delegates `applicationDidBecomeActive` method.

Comment: Yes I think I will save if the app is in background, add an observer on willEnterForeground and do my stuff. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you call UI functions from the background the result is unpredictable.  Just explicitly present on the main thread.  Here is a simplified example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.doBackgroundStuff()
    }

    func getThread() -> String {
        return Thread.isMainThread ? "UI" : "BG"
    }

    func doBackgroundStuff() {
        // force to background
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            print("doBackgroundStuff: this is the \(self.getThread()) thread")
            self.showPopup(on: self)
        }
    }

    func showPopup(on viewController: UIViewController) {
        print("showPopup OUTER: this is the \(self.getThread()) thread")
        // force to foreground
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            print("showPopup INNER: this is the \(self.getThread()) thread")
            let popup = PresentingViewController(nibName: "PresentingViewController", bundle: nil)
            viewController.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The UI is shown and the output on the console is:

```
doBackgroundStuff: this is the BG thread
showPopup OUTER: this is the BG thread
showPopup INNER: this is the UI thread
```

Comment: My issue is when the app is in background during the async request

Comment: You cannot  expect to present a view controller when an app is in the background.  This is counter to Apple's guidelines.